# How to write better validation/ test cases in python

Tags: python-3.x, validation, testing, testcase

There is an object which has few properties. I wrote a function for test cases which check if the properties are satisfied or not. The function should throw an exception if the property is not satisfied.

But, I think there are better ways to write those test cases. 
A subset of the property of the object is as follows:

> x['polygon'] is a list of >= 3 integer (x,y) pairs representing the
>   corners of the polygon in clockwise or anticlockwise order.

Current function is as follows:

```
def validate_object(x):
    """This function validates an object x that is supposed to represent an object
    inside an image, and throws an exception on failure.
    Specifically it is checking that:
      x['polygon'] is a list of >= 3 integer (x,y) pairs representing the corners
                    of the polygon in clockwise or anticlockwise order.
    """
    if type(x) != dict:
        raise ValueError('dict type input required.')

    if 'polygon' not in x:
        raise ValueError('polygon object required.')

    if not isinstance(x['polygon'], (list,)):
        raise ValueError('list type polygon object required.')

    points_list = x['polygon']
    if len(points_list) < 3:
        raise ValueError('More than two points required.')

    for x, y in points_list:
        if type(x) != int or type(y) != int:
            raise ValueError('integer (x,y) pairs required.')

    return
```

It would be really helpful if someone could please suggest better ways of writing those test cases.